# Undefined offset: 1 error daterange explode array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I get value form date range and use explode to array error line whereBetween

```
$range = Input::get('daterange') ;
    $date = explode('to', $range);
    //dd($date);

    $temp = Temps::select('temp')
        ->orderBy('date_temp', 'asc')
        ->whereBetween('date_temp',[$date[0], $date[1]])
        ->get()
        ->pluck('temp');
```

> 1/1) ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

Comment: can you post $range result

Comment: Please can you print the $range content
or the Input::get('daterange')

Comment: dd($range) = "09/11/2017 - 10/10/2017"

Comment: dd{$date) = array:1 [▼
  0 => "09/11/2017 - 10/10/2017"
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change since range is `$range='09/11/2017 - 10/10/2017';`.you need to split using `-`

```
$date = explode('-', $range);
```

if you print  `$date`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09/11/2017 
    [1] =>  10/10/2017
)
```

Also note you can pass data directly.You will get instead of `[$date[0], $date[1]` since `whereBetween` accept array and also `$date` is an array

```
$temp = Temps::select('temp')
        ->orderBy('date_temp', 'asc')
        ->whereBetween('date_temp',$date)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('temp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$date = explode('-', $range);
```

You were trying to explode your variable with a string who doesn't exist in your variable, that's why you are getting the same variable with only one array in your `$date`